# Why are these two methods of printing 2d lists different(python)

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

```
board = [[] for i in range(3)]
for i in board:
    for j in range(3):
        i.append(' ')

for i in board:print(i)
''' 
['', '', '']
['', '', '']
['', '', '']'''
print(i for i in board) #<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000026E45CB69E8>
```

Why do the last two lines print two different things?

Comment: Because the `i for i in board` statement is **not a `for` loop**, it is a generator expression.

Comment: First, consider why you ever expected them to print the same thing.

Comment: I mean, from my limited experience with python, these two have worked in the same way in the past ex - for i in range(3):print(i) . and print(i for i in range(3))

Comment: @MehulGhosal: [You've remembered your experiences wrong.](http://ideone.com/H7umer) Those code snippets don't do the same thing either.